# Why is Spock's mother alive in Star Trek IV?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

I just watch Star Trek IV and I noticed that Spock was talking to his mother. This baffled me greatly since when I watched the latest Star Trek movie (based on a very young Kirk and Spock) the planet he came from was destroyed, taking with it a very young mother of Spock.

Is there a reason for this or is it a movie mistake?

Comment: The timelines changed. The new trek films are in an alternative universe, because he writers were too lazy to come up with new stories or characters and everything needs a reboot these days

Comment: Have a look at the dupe question. The new films are a wholly new timeline with **events that never occurred the original films and TV shows**.

Comment: Nero went back in time and destroyed Vulcan. The movies and TV shows before the reboot exist in a previous timeline, the one Nero and old-Spock came from. In the old timeline, Vulcan exists into TNG (as seen in "Reunification"). In the new timeline, Vulcan is destroyed, Biff is powerful and corrupt, and Bill & Ted failed history.